# Why does Firefox stop calling the progress event?

Tags: jquery, firefox, html5-video

I am preloading an html5 video, and it seems that Firefox is only calling the progress event twice, then giving up. I'm checking to make sure I have data before doing any loading and all looks well.

Here is how I am setting up my listeners:

**jquery**

```
var video = document.createElement('video');

....

if (Modernizr.video && Modernizr.video.webm) {
    video.setAttribute('src', '/resources/video/myvideo.webm');
} else if (Modernizr.video && Modernizr.video.ogg) {
    video.setAttribute('src', '/resources/video/myvideo.ogv');
} else if (Modernizr.video && Modernizr.video.h264) {
    video.setAttribute('src', '/resources/video/myvideo.mp4');
}

video.setAttribute('id', 'myvideoid');
video.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
video.setAttribute('autobuffer', 'true');
video.setAttribute('autoplay', 'true');  

$(video).insertBefore('#mydiv');

if (video.readyState > 1) {
    console.log('HAVE META DATA');
} else {
    console.log('NO META DATA');
    var checkVideoMeta = setInterval(function () {
        if (video.readyState > 1) {
            console.log('OK NOW HAVE META DATA');
            video.addEventListener('progress', onProgress, false);
            video.addEventListener('loaded', onProgress, false);
            video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', onProgress, false);
            clearInterval(checkVideoMeta);
        }
    }, 30);
}

var onProgress = function (e) {
    var percent = null;
    if (video) {
        console.log('YES VIDEO');

        if (video.buffered) {
            video.play();  // doesn't seem to make much difference
            console.log('video is buffered');
            console.log(video.buffered.length);
            console.log(video.buffered.end(0));
            console.log(video.duration);

            if (video && video.buffered && video.buffered.length > 0 && video.buffered.end(0) && video.duration) {
                percent = video.buffered.end(0) / video.duration;
            }
        } else {
            console.log('video not buffered');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('NO VIDEO');
    }

    if (percent !== null) {
        percent = Math.round(100 * (Math.min(1, Math.max(0, percent))));
        $('#feedbackStatus span').text(percent + '%');

        if (percent == '100') {
            onLoadComplete();
        }
    }
};
```

Chrome, Safari seem to work well. Chrome will roll through the loading & Safari generally jumps from zero to 100 (Which is fine). However, this is what I get with Firefox:

```
NO META DATA
OK NOW HAVE META DATA
YES VIDEO
video is buffered 
1 
0.074 
34.056 
YES VIDEO
video is buffered
1
0.074
34.056
```

...and that's it. I'm not sure why Firefox just gives up while the other browsers keep rolling through the progress event.

**EDIT**

I found/saw that from [this post](http://tiffanybbrown.com/2010/07/05/the-html5-video-progress-event/) that

> Firefox requests partial content on the initial page load, then pauses downloading until the play event is fired. After the play event is fired — whether when the user clicks the ‘play’ button or the video tag has the autoplay attribute — Firefox resumes downloading the video file.

So I have added `video.play()` within the event listener (above) but not much has changed.

It's also worth noting that all of this only applies to the first time I visit the page. Any subsequent or even refresh, the video is instantly loaded (cashed) and plays perfectly.